# in firebug, how to ignore new ActiveXObject() break

Tags: javascript, firebug

for reason I don't know, firebug constantly stop every time a line contains `new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash')`, even when surrounded by `try...catch` (but no error are displayed in the console)

I cannot "disable" it because everytime I change something, the offset created make it useless.

See that code if you want to reproduce.

```
function getFlashVersion(){
 // ie
 try {
  try {
   // avoid fp6 minor version lookup issues
   // see: http://blog.deconcept.com/2006/01/11/getvariable-setvariable-crash-internet-explorer-flash-6/
   var axo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6');
   try { axo.AllowScriptAccess = 'always'; }
   catch(e) { return '6,0,0'; }
  } catch(e) {}
  return new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash').GetVariable('$version').replace(/\D+/g, ',').match(/^,?(.+),?$/)[1];
  // other browsers
 } catch(e) {
  try {
   if(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin){
    return (navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]).description.replace(/\D+/g, ",").match(/^,?(.+),?$/)[1];
   }
  } catch(e) {}
 }
 return '0,0,0';
}
var flash_version = getFlashVersion();
```

I got that error since a couple of firebug version, currently running on 1.12.4 if that matters

**EDIT:** I take a screenshot to make a better explanation of the problem.

[image: ActiveXObject is not defined, You can disable/enable break notifications in panel's tab menu.]

```
ActiveXObject is not defined 
You can disable/enable break notifications in panel's tab menu.
```

The "Copy" button will copy the error message with the line number.
The "Disable" button will disable that exact line (regardless of its content). So if I add or remove a line before that one, the "disable point" will be different.

Also, as mentioned above, no error at are displayed in the console (there is some warning about "assignment to undeclared variable", but they are not related to theses breaks)

Comment: What do you mean by "firebug constantly stop every time"? Does the script execution stop at that line? Does Firebug not react anymore?

Comment: yes, on each of theses "ActiveX" lines the script executions stops, popping a message about this being not defined and ask if I want to disable that line for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click the [*Break On All Errors* button ([image: Break On All Errors button])](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Break_On_All_Errors) inside the Console panel to deactivate stopping the execution on JavaScript errors.

**Edit**:
There is a related problem in Firebug, which is causing this behavior. Currently (in versions up to 1.12.4) the option [*Track Throw/Catch* isn't working](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3276), i.e. Firebug will always break on errors even when they are surrounded by a try/catch block. This will be fixed as soon as Firebug has [switched to a new debugger API](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421). This is [planned for the next major release](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php?title=Firebug_2.0_Roadmap).

Furthermore there is an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3168) for enabling correcting the line number of a persistent breakpoint in case the script has changed.

Until the behavior of the *Track Throw/Catch* option is fixed you have to either disable *Break On All Errors* as described above, move the disabled breakpoints manually when the line number of the `ActiveXObject()` calls has changed or just continue the script execution.

Sebastian

Comment: this will deactivate ALL breaks, and that's not what I want

Comment: but thanks you for the try ;) . I added a screenshot to more explanation on the problem

Comment: I edited my answer to explain in more detail why you see that problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. I suppose this is the best answer I would have :/